# Find a complex non-constant function bounded throughout the complex plane, that is analytic in a region (not everywhere), and defined everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I am trying to find a non-constant function that satisfies these 3 conditions:

a) defined everywhere
b) not analytic everywhere
c) bounded in the complex plane meaning we can find a value $M$ such that $|f(z)| ≤ M$ for all values of $z$

I've thought of $|z|$ but that is not bounded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you require $f$ to be continuous? And you should add the requirement that $f$ is analytic in some region.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\begin{cases}z&\text{if }\lvert z\rvert<1\\ \sin(\operatorname{Re} z)&\text{if }\lvert z\rvert\ge 1\end{cases}$ certainly has those properties.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you!

Comment: $f$ is not continuous (although this was not reqiured). You have $f(i) = 0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Fair enough, but if I start making up requirements until I like this question better, where does it end? For me, either never or very soon.

Comment: @Elli Since you like the answer, you should give feedback by accepting and /or upvoting. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers..

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}z&\lvert z\rvert \le 1\\ \frac{z}{\lvert z \rvert}&\lvert z\rvert \ge 1\end{cases}$$